# Preventing htaccess rewrite condition

Tags: url-rewriting

I am using this rewrite condition to rewrite urls like domain.com to

> www.domain.com

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

problem is that it is also redirecting mobile version of url. i.e.

> m.domain.com to www.m.domain.com

How can I prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

If your only problem is to prevent `m.domain.com` to trigger the rule, then you can add it to your conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www|m\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```